# Notepad++ RegEx replace with pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find the following pattern:

```
Image not found: /Images/IMG-20160519-WA0015.jpg
```

And replace with some markup, including the image name from the above text like:

```
<a href="IMG-20160519-WA0015.jpg"><img src="IMG-20160519-WA0015.jpg" width="180" height="240" alt="IMG-20160519-WA0015.jpg" class="image" />
```

Is it possible with some kind of Regex or plugin or I'm simply burning neurones?

Thanks.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Why you're being so rude? Why are you down voting in such manner?
I don't agree with you.
Is that Regex is not almost a way coding itself? (that I don't master. obviously)
Also I searched and found plenty of notepad++ and regex there in stackoverflow and assumed it was a valid question. Why banning this particular one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try finding `^Image not found: \/Images\/(IMG-.*\.jpg)` and replacing with `<a href="\1"><img src="\1" width="180" height="240" alt="\1" class="image" />`

Note that the caret (^) in the regex says that it must be at the beginning of the line, not sure if that's the case for you but I suspect that it is.  I also assumed that the "IMG-" prefix is constant, if not then you can just remove those four characters from the regex.

If you're not aware of it, [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) is a nice interactive way to build and test regular expressions.

EDIT: Since you mentioned having trouble in the comments, here's an image of my settings:
[image]

Comment: Sadly it doesn't find anything.. I've tested in the normal replace (with regexp) and TextFX one. Thanks for your help thou.

Comment: It's working fine for me with normal built-in regex find-replace -- is the "Image not found" text at the beginning of the line?

Comment: It's indented. It has 14 spaces before. But I've tried by adding them and doesn't work either.

Comment: Try `^\s*Image not found: \/Images\/(IMG-.*\.jpg)`
The \s* says to ignore whitespace before the "Image not found" bit.  You can also try just removing the caret - that should find it anywhere.

Comment: Glad to help - I'm _guessing_ that those 14 spaces may have been a mix of other whitespace characters (e.g. tab) and that's why it didn't find them when you added them directly to your regex...